# Insert Date value into MS access

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, oledb, oledbcommand

I was trying to insert value from Windows Form DateTimePicker into an Access table, and yet I get no error the inserted date is always the time 00:01:11 and not the chosen date.

When I am debugging, The INSERT command syntax looks like that:

```
"INSERT into Products (productionDate) VALUES (05/03/2016)"
```

Though it is successfully added to the table, the inserted value becomes 00:01:11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pertinent to MS Access SQL, use the following syntax:

```
"INSERT into Products (productionDate) VALUES (#05/03/2016#)"
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: You are welcome. I am glad it works for you. Should you have more questions, please post them separately. Best regards,